# Move Identity account pages

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have already added Identity to my existing .net core application. I have added scaffolded Identity elements to have ability to replace views with custom code.
In result I got files structured in that way:

[image]

Everything is ok at this point. Every changes I made in Login.cshtml are visible. But when I want to move Views from Account folder into Pages then when I want to login in my application I see default Login view - my changes are omitted.
Have you got any idea what more should I do to make it working?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you use the `Login.cshtml` file? I think it has to do something with the namespaces. It tries to find the old `Login.cshtml` but the namespace might've changed when you've moved the file, so it defaults to the default Login view. If you're moving the file from Account to Pages, make sure to change the namespace to reflect the folder structure, and also change the new namespace everywhere you use it.